# Sum of roots with residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus, analytic-functions

could you help me with the following problem or at least give some ideas?

Let $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a polynomial of degree $2n$ defined as follows: $$F(x)=(x+i)^{2n+1}-(x-i)^{2n+1}$$

Now, let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ be the distinct roots of the equation 
$$F(cotx)=0$$.
The task is to find the sum 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (cot(\alpha_k))^2$$

---

This is a homework problem from the complex analysis course which should be solved using the Residue Theorem.

We also have a hint that there is a polynomial $W$ of degree $n$ such that $W(x^2)=F(x)$.

Comment: It may use a standard application of the Residue Theorem: The Argument Principle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle

Comment: I haven't really seen any applications of the Argument Principle yet ,so I don't see how it  relates to this problem. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Maybe it is better for you to play around with the Argument Principle. You'll find some useful stuff at the Applications part of the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Ok, I see that indeed the "generelized" argument principle may be usefull but can I safely apply it to a function going from $\mathbb{R}$ and not from $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: You'll have to extend $F$ to $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: You can get the proper font for $\cot$ by using `\cot`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.